# XOR operation in C++

Tags: c++

How does the XOR logical operator work on more than two values?

For instance, in an operation such as  `1 ^ 3 ^ 7`?

```
0 0 0 1 // 1

0 0 1 1 // 3

0 1 1 1 // 7

__

0 1 0 1 // 5
```

for some reason yields 0 1 0 1, where as it should have, as I thought, yielded: 0 1 0 0, since XOR is only true when strictly one of the operands is true.

Comment: There's no "logical XOR" operator, only bitwise XOR.

Comment: "How does the XOR logical operator works on more than two values?" - the **bitwise** XOR operator is left-associative.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because of the operator precedence and because the `xor` is a binary operator, which in this case is left-to-right.

First `1 ^ 3` is evaluated

```
0 0 0 1 // 1

0 0 1 1 // 3
-------
0 0 1 0 // 2
```

The result is 2, then this number is the first operand of the last xor operation (`2 ^ 7`)

```
0 0 1 0 // 2  

0 1 1 1 // 7
-------
0 1 0 1 // 5
```

The result is 5.

Answer (score 4):

1. XOR works bitwise, XORing each position separately
2. XOR is commutative, so a^b = b^a
3. XOR is associative, so (a^b)^c = a^(b^c)

Using this, a human can count the number of ones in a given position and the result bit is set exactly for an odd number of ones in the given position of the operands.

Counting ones yields (0101)binary=5

Comment: You may want to explain what each of those actually means and the implications thereof.

Comment: I don't think in the context of C++ (with operator overloading) XOR can be counted on to be associative, or commutative.

Answer (score 4):

`1 ^ 3 ^ 7` is not a function of three arguments, it is:  `(1 ^ 3) ^ 7` which equals `2 ^ 7` which equals `5`.

Though actually this `^` operator is associative: each bit in the result will be set if and only if an odd number of the operands had the bit set.

Answer (score 3):

The expression is parsed as `(1 ^ 3) ^ 7` so you first get

```
 0001 ^ 0011
```

which is `0010`. The rest is

```
 0010 ^ 0111
```

which is `0101`

Answer (score 0):

^ is a binary operator. It doesn't work on all three numbers at once, i.e. it's (1^3)^7, which is:

1 ^ 3 == 2

2 ^ 7 == 5